# How to Investigate Pointwise and Uniform Convergence of the Series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can we  investigate pointwise and uniform convergence of the following series:
   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n},\ x\in \mathbb{R}?$$

Comment: For $x \neq 0$, compare with a geometric series. For $x=0$ your series is zero due to the $x^2$ in the numerator.

Answer (score 3):

Pointwise convergence can be established by considering the sum of a geometric series.

However, the series fails to converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.

Either observe that the limit function is discontinuous at $x=0$ or see that the sequence of partial sums does not satisfy the Cauchy criterion uniformly, since

$$\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}\left|\sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^k}\right| \geqslant\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}\left|\sum_{k = n+1}^{2n} \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^k}\right| \geqslant \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}\frac{nx^2}{(1+x^2)^{2n}} \\\geqslant \frac{n(1/\sqrt{n})^2}{(1+(1/\sqrt{n})^2)^{2n}} = \frac{1}{(1 + 1/n)^{2n}} \to \frac{1}{e^2} \neq 0$$

Recall that for uniform convergence we require

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}\left|\sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^k}\right| = 0$$